# stuck on assignment in C

Tags: c

Hi I'm completely new to programming and for my intro to programming class, I'm having some issues with this assignment. I need some help with solving the issue which is creating a program that outputs the total rainfall, average rainfall, largest rainfall, and the smallest rainfall amount. Everything is fine up until the output of the smallest rainfall amount which keeps outputting as 0.0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 5

double getValidRainfall(){
    double result;

    printf("Enter a rainfall amount: ");
    scanf("%lf", &result);

    while (result < 0.0){
        printf("%.2lf is not a valid rainfall amount.", result);
        printf("\nEnter a rainfall amount: ");
        scanf("%lf", &result);
    }

    return result;
}

double calculateTotal (double rainfall[], int size){
    double result = 0.0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        result += rainfall[i];
    }
    return result;
}

double findLargest(double rainfall[], int size){
    double result = 0.0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(rainfall[i] > result)
            result = rainfall[i];
    }
    return result;
}

// I believe the problem is located right under here and...

double findSmallest(double rainfall[], int size){
    double result = 0.0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(rainfall[i] < result)
            result = rainfall[i];
    }
    return result;
}

    // here.. Just can't seem to find the issue that will output the correct smallest
    // amount of rainfall.

int main(){
    double rainfall[SIZE], totalRainfall, averageRainfall;
    double largestRainfall, smallestRainfall;
    int i;

    for( i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        rainfall[i] = getValidRainfall();


    totalRainfall = calculateTotal(rainfall, SIZE);
    averageRainfall = totalRainfall / SIZE;
    largestRainfall = findLargest(rainfall, SIZE);
    smallestRainfall = findSmallest(rainfall, SIZE);

    printf("Thank you\n");
    printf("The total rainfall is %.2lf\n", totalRainfall);
    printf("The average rainfall is %.2lf\n", averageRainfall);
    printf("The largest daily rainfall is %.1lf\n", largestRainfall);
    printf("The smallest daily rainfall is %.1lf\n", smallestRainfall);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In `findSmallest` you start off with:

```
double result = 0.0;
```

Then you only update this if the rainfall is smaller. However, presuming no places have a negative rainfall, this means it will still end up with 0.0 .

To make this algorithm work you should start it off at a value at least as high as any actual rainfall, e.g.

```
 if ( size == 0 )
     return 0.0;

 double result = rainfall[0];
```

Comment: Better to return an impossible value for an empty array, `DBL_MAX` or maybe just `-1`.

Comment: @Keith I guess it depends on requirements. The caller can already detect the zero case by checking the size before they invoke the function, so we don't need to provide out-of-band exception reporting.  My main point was to avoid undefined behaviour by doing `rainfall[0]` on the empty input.

Answer (score 1):

In `findSmallest`, initialise `result` to a big number, greater than all the possibilities.

E.g,

```
#include <float.h>

double result = DBL_MAX;
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused because the input can be anything over 0, meaning it is infinite. How would that work?

Comment: All possible entries in the passed array will have to be less than `DBL_MAX`, so the first array element will be assigned to `result`, if there is one. Using `DBL_MAX` has the advantage of unambiguous behaviour in the event that the array size is zero.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you're initializing the result to 0.0 in your findSmallest function. Unless you have negative rainfall, you will never find anything smaller than that. instead, initialize result to a large value in that function.

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
double findSmallest(double rainfall[], int size){
double result = 0.0;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
if(i == 0)
    result = rainfall[i];
if(rainfall[i] < result)
    result = rainfall[i];
}
return result;
```

Code is self-explanatory as where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `findSmallest` starts with an assumption of 0.0, then looks for negative rainfall. Use the first value from `rainfall[]` as your initial value, instead.